# Checking if a value is in the array

Tags: php, arrays, isset

I am trying to check if I have the `$subCat` value in the array then don't add it.  I should end up with one of each `$subCat` but when I dump `$details` I am still getting the full array.  Why is this?

```
foreach ($detailsFunction as $main) 
{
        $mainlisting = $main['listingId'];
        $mainCat     = strtolower($main['mainCat']);
        $subCatO     = strtolower($main['subCat']);
        $subCat      = str_replace(" ", "-", $subCatO);

        if(isset($subCat) && $subCat == $subCat)
        {

          $details[] = array('url'     => base_url().'listings/'.$mainCat.'/'.$subCat,
                         'mainCat' => $main['mainCat'],
                         'subCat'  => $main['subCat']   
                        );
        }
}
```

Comment: In which array do you want to check if `$subCat` exists? Right now you're just checking if the variable is set, and if it equals itself (which will always be true)

Comment: @freejosh ahh thanks.  I am trying to check the $details[]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you concerned with keeping the keys of `$details` numeric? If not You could add each item with `$subCat` as its key, and check if the key exists before adding it:

```
foreach ($detailsFunction as $main) 
{
        $mainlisting = $main['listingId'];
        $mainCat     = strtolower($main['mainCat']);
        $subCatO     = strtolower($main['subCat']);
        $subCat      = str_replace(" ", "-", $subCatO);

        if(!array_key_exists($subCat, $details))
        {

          $details[$subCat] = array('url'     => base_url().'listings/'.$mainCat.'/'.$subCat,
                         'mainCat' => $main['mainCat'],
                         'subCat'  => $main['subCat']   
                        );
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Josh Thats what I wanted